# Select from table using command prompt (not browser) in Laravel framewok

Tags: php, laravel, console, command-prompt

I want to select all data from 1 table in command prompt (not from browser) using Laravel framework. Is there anyone know what the good references is? please give me link, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
php artisan tinker
```

Then:

```
DB::table('users')->get()
```

Comment: Did you mean, i have to code it in console everytime i want to execute it?

Comment: You haven't explained what you want to do with the data. All you said is that you want to "select" it.

Comment: i am sorry, its my faultness

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Artisan Command.

Check the Laravel 5.0 docs:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/commands

Then, you can run you command. Example:

```
php artisan mycommand:list
```

Laravel 4.2:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands

You can run artisan commands from "cmd" (Windows). (Edit your environment variables first! Add you PHP path).

Comment: i am using laravel 4.2, fyi.

Where should I execute the command? like from public (C:\xampp\htdocs\tugasakhir\public)  ?

Comment: Where should I execute the command? like from public (C:\xampp\htdocs\tugasakhir\public) ?

Comment: ya, i know from cmd and edit my environment variable. But in which folder i should execute it?

Comment: i found the way to display text in console (thank you) inside fire method in my command class. but i dont know how to display data from database here. should i make view in fire ?method

Comment: finally i found the way, I have to put like this in fire method
$this->info(SelectAll::all());

Thank you so much